# PyGame2Exe doesn't include spritesheet?

Tags: python, pygame

My directory for my Pygame program looks something like this:

```
[Parent directory]
    lib
        engine
            Various .py files
        graphics
            spritesheet.py
            spritesheet.png
    skeleton.py (starter script)
    font.ttf
    spritesheet.png
    pygame2exe.py (Pygame2Exe script)
```

When I run pygame2exe.py (found [here](https://github.com/flembobs/pygame2exe), everything seems fine: the dist directory is created with an executable file and all the necessary dlls. However, when I try to run the program, it says I cannot find the file "lib\graphics\spritesheet.png"

I've tried to manually insert the image file by using 7zip to "open" the .exe; however 7zip doesn't support it. That seemed to be the best solution, but now I am stumped. Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In `pygame2exe.py`, there's a section which reads:

```
#Extra files to be included in the dist directory  
                  #directory #files 
extra_files = [ #("",        ["README.txt"]),
              ]
```

You should add your content (`spritesheet.png`, `font.ttf`) into this array and run pygame2exe again.

Comment: I tried something like this: `extra_files = [("lib/graphics", ["spritesheet.png"])]` however, the picture itself doesn't appear in the executable itself -- it appears in the dist/lib/graphics directory...

Comment: @Y-M that appears to be a limitation of pygame2exe itself - try changing your game code to look for all assets in a `dist` directory